# Woosh or Whoosh?

Tags: whoosh

What's the standard spelling of this word in the industry?

I've seen it both ways, and I want to just settle once and for all the proper, accepted way it's used. A quick search comes up with most people spelling it "Whoosh".

Please let me know your thoughts.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I default to 'whoosh'. I've seen 'woosh' but not often. Some people even call it a 'swoosh', 'swish' or 'wipe'!

Comment: Thanks for the rapid answer, Jay. I'm trying to find one of those fountains to record for you!

Comment: I concur.  I think I've only seen Woosh once.  Otherwise, always Whoosh

Comment: ditto.  i use the H

Answer (score 3):

wHoosh. The H adds the power! :P

Answer (score 2):

Whoosh is the standard way to spell this word.  Woosh is just a variant, onomatopoeic words sometimes have variants, such as yeah or yeh (yeh is the variant of yeah), or yea or yah.

Answer (score 1):

I use the H also, but i usually think of the whoosh as the big processed and i reserve swish for smaller sounding stuff like the spoon whips before processing.

Answer (score 1):

All in all i agree with Jay, though for me normally a whoosh is a form of non-diegetic stinger or transition, and swishes are diegetic movement, with swooshes as large-body ditto, like passing trains or tipping monoliths and such.

Answer (score 0):

I always spell it as whoosh. Interestingly though, when you want a swoosh, that word has no "H" after the "W"

Answer (score 0):

Whoosh is standard. Woosh is common across the pond (uk)... but for sfx libraries, always stick with the H!